# How to pass the autocompleted value into another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I tried to pass the autocomplete value into another function.

```
<body>
    <input id="automplete" name = "name"></input>
    <input type="submit" onclick="mufunc()"></input>
    <script>
        function mufunc(a){
            alert(a);
        }
        $(function() {
            var availableTutorials = [
                "ActionScript",
                "Boostrap",
                "C",
                "C++",
                "Ecommerce"
            ];
            $("#automplete").autocomplete({
                source: availableTutorials,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    if (ui.item) {
                        var seqps = new mufunc(ui.item.value);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Here autocomplete is works fine.  I tried, it value pass into the `mufunc()` function and when i enter submit button that time only alert the autocompleted  value.

But in my script when i fill the text field that time execute the `mufunc()` function. How can i manage it?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I removed and run it but not get the result.

Comment: It wouldn't help your specific issue, but it's better practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body>
    <input id="automplete" name = "name"></input>
    <input type="submit" onclick="mufunc()"></input>
    <script>
        function mufunc(){
            var a=document.getElementById('automplete').value;
            alert(a);
        }
        $(function() {
            var availableTutorials = [
                "ActionScript",
                "Boostrap",
                "C",
                "C++",
                "Ecommerce"
            ];
        $("#automplete").autocomplete({
            source: availableTutorials,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                if (ui.item) {
                    $('#automplete').val(ui.item.value);
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Without passing the varaible to another function it is possible. Because your `textfield` values is store into the `autoomplete` `id` then easily get the value of this id and do it.

Answer (score 0):

you enter submit button that time only alert the autocompleted value. you can try to pass input id into call the function onclick="mufunc(automplete)"